# Flutter - How to detect if popupmenu has been closed or user tapped out of the menu to close it?

Tags: flutter, popupmenu

I am showing a popupmenu by calling the showMenu() method inside my custom appbar widget.
I need to be able to detect if user closed the popupmenu in anyway.

I tried using GestureDetector but it only detects taps when the popupmenu is already closed which is not what I need.

```
    body: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => print('Tapped'),
      child: MyWidget(),
    ),
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can look at the `PopupMenuButton` documentation you will find it has a property called `onCancelled` you can read about it [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton/onCanceled.html)

Comment: How to do this from **showMenu** function? I need to open popupmenu dynamically and get callback when user closes it.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showMenu.html

Answer (score 0):

> showMenu method returns a value, you should wait for. It returns either null (if menu has been closed in ANYWAY) or any value(if user selected menu button)

```
final result = await showMenu(...)
// you can detect close event even if user just dismissed menu like this:
if(result==null){...do something}
else{...use result}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code.